# QuickContactBadge in ListView

Tags: android

I have a ListView which dynamically adds QuickContactBadge and a TextView to show contact names and their photo in QuickContactBadge. I am using the following code to show photo in QuickContactBadge...

```
public static Bitmap loadContactPhoto(ContentResolver cr, long  id) { 
     Uri uri = ContentUris.withAppendedId(ContactsContract.Contacts.CONTENT_URI, id); 
     InputStream input = ContactsContract.Contacts.openContactPhotoInputStream(cr, uri);

      if (input == null) {  
       return null;    
      }
      return BitmapFactory.decodeStream(input);
     }
```

Then i am calling this method by saying

```
quickContactBadge.setImageBitmap(loadContactPhoto(getContentResolver(), contactId));
```

I have following problem

1) The image is getting displayed, but it is huge. how to control size of quickcontactbadge.
2) Is this the best way to show image of a contact in quickContactBadge or if there is a preferred way, please let me know.

Thanks

Answer (score 0):

To answer your 1) question: you can use Bitmap.createScaledBitmap to scale a bitmap to a given size.